# Sort report with subtotals and corresponding details by category,subtotal amount largest to smalled then by vendor name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I start off with a full download of data then add subtotals by category and vendor name.  The end result I need is a report that is sorted first by category, then by largest to smallest dollar amount by vendor name within the category.  Important part I keep loosing is the detail data forming the subtotal summation.

see example below:

```
    tech subtotal   $14,308,342
GENERAL SERVICES    nor $20,314,000
GENERAL SERVICES    nor $3,200,000
    nor subtotal    $23,514,000
GENERAL SERVICES    le  $20,314,000
GENERAL SERVICES    le  $3,200,000
    le subtototal   $23,514,000
GENERAL SERVICES    ce  $22,500,000
GENERAL SERVICES    ce  $1,000,000
    ce subtotal $23,500,000
GENERAL SERVICES    po  $22,500,000
    po subtotal $22,500,000
GENERAL SERVICES    te  $20,314,000
    te subtotal $20,314,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICESOFESSIONAL SERVICES    b1  $3,000,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b2  $495,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b3  $450,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b4  $400,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b5  $250,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b6  $230,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b7  $230,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b8  $180,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b9  $110,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b10 $75,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b11 $75,000
PROFESSIONAL SERVICES   b12 $75,000
    b1-12 subtota   $5,570,000
```

Comment: Hi Amy, can you tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what Pivot Tables are for.

Select all data, go to `Insert` > `PivotTable` and drag the fields between the row, column, filter, and value fields as needed.